# When I click on 'remember me' and after sign out, when I try again to login cookies are not retrieved

Tags: php

I have a login form in which i have a username, password and a *remember me* radio button option. Now I want it so that when I've signed out from home page and I try again to login then without asking for a username and password I get logged in because I am going to store the username and password values into cookie.

I wrote code on password_match.php page(action page of login page)

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
die('Could Not Connect:'.mysql_error());
} 

mysql_select_db("tcs",$con);

if(isset($_COOKIE['cookname']) && isset($_COOKIE['cookpass']))
{
$usr = $_COOKIE['cookname'];
$pwd = $_COOKIE['cookpass'];
$pwd=hash('sha1',$_POST['password']);
}

else
{
$usr=$_POST["username"];                 
$pwd=hash('sha1',$_POST['password']);           
}
```

Through this code I am checking is there any cookie with cookname and cookpassword which contain username and password. If no cookie is found with this name then retrieve username and password from textboxes directly, if the user enters them.

Now the code which I am going to write will set a cookie if username and password exists:

if ($result) 
{
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

```
if (($row["Username"]==$usr) && ($row["Password"]==$pwd))
{
    if(isset($_POST['remember']))
    {
    setcookie("cookname", $row['Username'], time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
    setcookie("cookpass", $row['Password'], time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
    }


$_SESSION['employee']['id']=$row['User Id'];
    $_SESSION['employee']['username']=$row['Username'];

    header ("Location: home_page.php");
```

}

Now when starting, when I enter username and password and if these are right show a cookie must have been set and if now I am signed out and try the same sign in form, as according to me it should retrive cookie but nothing happining here. I am not able to implement it.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Don't store the password in a cookie. That's a really bad idea. You shouldn't need to store their login info at all. Just log them in and then mark them as authorized then check for that. Do it securely of course.

Comment: will u tell me in detail plz..

Comment: See my answers below. Follow that article and create 2 cookies. 1 is normal cookies and 1 is persistent that have long expiration time (a year or more).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brief overview of a simple system. Create a table that looks like:

`auth_token { user_id int, token varchar(...) }`

When a person clicks "remember me" create a unique, impossible-to-guess token and store it in the `auth_token` table along with the associated `user_id`. Save that `token` as a cookie.

Now inside some `common.inc.php` file (i.e., included on every page), check for that hash value in the cookie if the person isn't currently logged in. If that cookie contains a valid hash, automatically log the person in as that user.

Some things to consider:

- You could tie the cookie to a range of IP Addresses
- You could have it expire after X number of days
- You could treat an auto-login as a "soft login" and require the password to be entered on the first action that is considered unsafe

Only if the user clicks on a "Log Out" link, do you delete the cookie from the computer. Optionally you could have a "Log Me Out of Every Location" in which you'd delete all the hashes from the databases associated with that user.

But whatever you do, **don't** store the username or password in the cookie. That is a major security hole.

Comment: i m just new on php and i am not so expert that will understand all these things plz tell me in above code where i am getting wrong

Answer (score 1):

Well, I design remember me cookies in my website according to this article: http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice

You should read it to know how to design the persistent cookies, and prevent stolen cookies from wreak havoc the user's data.

In my application, user that using persistent cookies to logged on is limited to view only action. Action that will change data require user to login using login form. Much more like the one used in yahoo mail.